# Windows 10 Ubuntu X11 with Xming (xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0)

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, x11-forwarding, vcxsrv

I am running ubuntu app on windows 10 (64b) same as on my other machine, exact same configuration with Xming for X11 but I am getting

xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0

I noticed that there was no `~/.Xauthority` so I followed some steps to make one and this is what I got:

```
[]$ xauth generate :0 . trusted
xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently Xming and export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 does not work ANYMORE... I do not know why yet, I will update here if I learn.

What works is the following:
VcXsrv with `-ac` option - THIS IS IMPORTANT... and for DISPLAY you should set the x server IP address whcih could be found here `/ets/resolv/conf`. You can simply put this in your `~/.bashrc`

`export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0`

Enjoy